# Pass function as an object in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization

My DF has a col ("some_field") that in some cases is of type **String**, and in others **Integer**.

I would like to have one piece of code to handle both, and I would like to do the check in the driver side and pass the handling function to the executors.

I've tried the following but got a *java.io.NotSerializableException* exception:

```
public static Dataset<Row> staticFunc(Dataset<Row> ds) {
    int fieldIndex = ds.schema().fieldIndex("some_field");
    final DataType dataType = ds.schema().fields()[fieldIndex].dataType();


    // the some_field field can be either String or Integer
    // moving the parseToIntFunc code to lambda below obviously works, but I don't want
    // to make this decision for every row
    Function<Object, Integer> parseToIntFunc = dataType instanceof IntegerType ?
            obj -> (int) obj :
            obj -> Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
    
    return ds.filter((FilterFunction<Row>) row -> {
        try {
            // passing the **parseToIntFunc** here triggers the exception
            int val = parseToIntFunc.apply(row.getAs("some_field"));
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    });
}
```

I know that doing the same in Scala is very simple as functions are objects, but I looking for a Java solution, please note that the java.util.function.Function interface is not serializable as well.